# testing ember fixture data with quint

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, qunit

How can we test ember data with fixtures using quint test? 
Here is how my test code looks like:

```
/*globals App, getFoodController*/

module('Analytics Unit Test: AnalyticsConfig Controller', {
  setup: function () {

      AS.Store = DS.Store.extend({
          adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create({ simulateRemoteResponse: false })
      });

      AS.AnalyticsRun.FIXTURES = [{
          id: 1,
          analyticsPlan: "Jane Q. Public",
          commandScript: "some script",
          analyticsRunParameters: []
      }];
  }
});

test('Check controller is initialized',function(){
    var controller = getAnalyticsConfigController();
    ok(controller, 'AnalyticsConfig controller is ok');
});


test('Check data',function(){
    var controller = getAnalyticsConfigController();
    var store = controller.get('store');
    var data;
    Ember.run(function () {
        data = store.find('analyticsRun',1);
        console.log(data);
    });
    equal(data.length, 1, 'Check data');
});
```

When I log the data, it returns a promise. But how do I test how many records were returned or check the data?

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `store.find` performs an async load, even the data in fixture being in memory. That aproach is used to simulate an ajax request. So you need to use the `then` method to know when the data is loaded.

To test async behavior in qunit you need to use the [asyncTest](http://api.qunitjs.com/asyncTest/).

Updating your sample, gives the following code:

```
asyncTest('Check data', 1, function() {
    var controller = getAnalyticsConfigController();
    var store = controller.get('store');
    Ember.run(function () {
        store.find('analyticsRun',1).then(function(data) {
            equal(data.get('length'), 1, 'Analytcs with id 1 found');
            start();
        });
    });
});
```

I hope it helps

**UPDATE**

Now I have realized that you use `simulateRemoteResponse: false` so ins't needed to use asyncTest. But the `then` method is still needed, because is where you retrieve the fetched model:

```
test('Check data', function() {
  var controller = AS.__container__.lookup('controller:analyticsConfig');
  var store = controller.get('store');
  Ember.run(function () {
    store.find('analyticsRun',1).then(function(analyticsRun) {                
      equal(analyticsRun.get('analyticsPlan'), 'Test', 'Analytics with id 1 found');                
    });        
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, your help is much appreciated. This solution does not throw any hard javascript error but the test gets stuck on running state. Would you know why this happens?

Comment: You are welcome! Can you put this test in a jsfiddle? I tried to do this, but I don't know the `getAnalyticsConfigController` implementation

Comment: Hi there, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/3dskY/1/. But in the example I have not implemented the controller, I was thinking we might not need it, because I want to test just the data in store.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/qUU4u/. Now I realized that you use `simulateRemoteResponse: false`, so the async test isn't needed. I will update the answer.

Comment: Yey this solved the problem. Thanks, thanks a lot, you don't know who many hours I spent to figure it out. I applied the code in the jsfiddle first and I was still getting error "Expected at least one assertion, but none were run - call expect(0) to accept zero assertions.". Then I started comparing line by line. I had a line of code AS.baseURL = "/platformservices/"; which was later used by my adapter like : AS.AnalyticsRunAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({   namespace: AS.baseURL.replace(/\//g,"")}); .I commented AS.baseURL out and it worked - I have no clew why it does that. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! In ember is complex to make tests at the moment. I expect this change in the future ...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
data = store.find('analyticsRun',1);
data.on('didLoad', function() {
    console.log(data.get('length')); //should output number of recs returned
});
```

Comment: I tried the code but it throws "data.on" is not a function error. I tried it both within Ember.run and outside of it and also within test and asyncTest.

Comment: Looks like it changed with the release sometime in the last 2 months or so, it's been a bit since I've worked on my ember project :( sorry about that

Comment: No problem, you took your time to help out some stranger :). Thanks again, you guys make this community rock.