# Ember Data's store promises don't work in quint tests

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

### **Update**

A bit of context into some quirks of the illustrative code below. `StoreProxy` exists as a model, created by the ApplicationRouter, that has a reference to the store. This lets other objects access the store directly (for singletons, tests, etc). Example:

```
MyApp.StoreProxy = DS.Model.extend();

MyApp.ApplicationRoute = U.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.createRecord('storeProxy');
  }
});
```

Before the route is executed, `StoreProxy` doesn't have a `store` property. After, it does. I can only assume this is because of some ember-data magic.

I very well realize your reaction to this may be "Ugh! No! You're doing it wrong!". Noted. We'll move to do it the right way from here over time. That said, this is where the code is now. So, given that, and given this method for getting a reference to the current store, why doesn't the code below call its accept or rejection handlers?

## Original question

I'm writing a qUnit unit test for ember. I'm using fixture data. The `findAll` call on the store isn't resolving or rejecting the promise.

```
test('Find all in store', function() {
  expect(1);
  var findPromise;
  findPromise = MyApp.StoreProxy.store.findAll('rule');
  findPromise.then(function(result) {
    console.log('yes');
    ok(true);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('no');
  });
});
```

I tried using async tests mentioned in this question:
[testing ember fixture data with quint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768598/testing-ember-fixture-data-with-quint) but the resolve and reject are never called, so the test hangs indefinitely.

I've also tried placing `Ember.run` calls around my code, in case it's a weird run loop thing. But to no avail.

```
 asyncTest('Find all in store', 1, function() {
   var findPromise;
   Ember.run(function() {
     findPromise = MyApp.StoreProxy.store.findAll('rule');
     findPromise.then(function(result) {
       console.log('yes');
       ok(true);
       start();
     }, function(error) {
       console.log('no');
       start();
     });
   });
 });
```

The code I'm testing runs fine when I run the application normally (fixture adapter or no), so it feels like something with the test environment.

Any thoughts on what to try? I'm stumped.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings in your console?

Comment: No warnings or errors. I attach a breakpoint for all thrown exceptions when the test begins and let it run; as far as I can tell no exceptions are thrown either.

Comment: Then I would say the most likely scenario is that the promise isn't being resolved by the store (or probably the adapter). Trace it through the adapter and see if it's ever resolved there. This problem might not have anything to do with testing or QUnit.

Comment: Breakpoints everywhere. I see a promise chain set up, from `#simulateRemote` on the fixture adapter, to `_findAll` to `extract payload` to the promise proxy returned from the store's `findAll` call. So far, so good. I then see the `#simulateRemote` promise resolved, as well as the `_findAll` promise. However, in resolving, that second promise has had its _subscribers reset to []. So the promise chain is broken, promise proxy is never resolved, and my handlers are never called. Still looking into why.

Comment: While publishing the #simulateRemote's promise, it tries to invoke the `_findAll` callback. This goes to a callback that calls one of `_guard`s inner functions, which sets all of the remaining subscribers to 0 and breaks the promise chain. Condition in guard fails because `_objectIsAlive` returned false. Not sure what object it's testing, why it's destroyed, or where `_guard` was called from originally.

Comment: Looks like the store itself is destroyed, even at the start of the test. Why would that be?

Comment: The testing environment in Ember is much different than the normal environment. For the most part, you have to explicitly set up everything involved in a test. I don't use Ember-Data, so I can't tell you how the store is bootstrapped during testing. My guess is that it isn't created at all since you shouldn't be testing the store.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you're writing your asynchronous tests is incorrect. Check out [QUnit's page on async testing](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.asyncTest/). Your test should look something like this:

```
asyncTest('Find all in store', function() {
    var findPromise = ...;

    findPromise.then(function(result) {
        start();
        ok(result);
    }, function() {
        start();
        ok(false);
    });
});
```

Specifically:

1. You put an extra parameter in the `asyncTest` function, which likely causes the test to not run at all.
2. You're using `Ember.Application.store`, which is not how you should access your store (and probably isn't even a valid store). I'm not sure what your context is, but you should be getting your store from elsewhere.
3. You're putting the `start()` calls *after* your assertions when they should be before.

Comment: I'll update the question. Turns out I had a few typos in recreating this from code, and there are a few quirky things our project does.

Comment: Updated the question to answer #2. That's how we're getting the store in the example code above.
#1. The docs appear to be outdated. The method sig for asyncTest in qunitjs@1.14.0 is `function(testName, expected, callback)`, although it's backwards-compatible when called with 2 args.
#3. Tried that. Order is irrelevant, as neither callback is called. So the async test hangs indefinitely, as `start` in either function is never called.

Any other ideas? I could really use the help.